# Reading in XML file with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am having trouble reading in the XML file with my C# program. When i try to run it I get an error saying that
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Expression must evaluate to a node-set."

XML Code:

```
<musicstore>
<album>
    <name>Black Album</name>
    <artist>Metallica</artist>
    <year>1991</year>
    <price>$10.00</price>
</album>

<album>
    <name>Exodus</name>
    <artist>Bob Marley</artist>
    <year>1979</year>
    <price>$5.99</price>
</album>

</musicstore>
```

C# Code:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("C:\\Users\\FJam\\Desktop\\Coding\\XML\\text.xml");

foreach(XmlNode node in xDoc.SelectNodes("musicstore/album/"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(node.SelectSingleNode("artist").InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Remove the last `/` on `musicstore/album/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.SelectNodes("musicstore/album"))
```

The problem is with the last `/`.